# How is the correct way to apply the '&'-Operator in my case and why?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to test if the last 16 bits matches a certain pattern (Header) in python. Therefore I pass the 64 bit stored in a string through `int()` and than apply the identification mask with `&`. Now i would expect, that only my Header would be found. But this is not the case and I don't understand right know why!

```
str1 = '0001111000000000000001110001101000000001010111010011001000100010'
str2 = '0111000000000000000001110001101011111111111100000011001000000000'

num1 = int(str1,2)
num2 = int(str2,2)

if (num1 & 0x3200) == 0x3200: # 0b0011001000000000
    print('I would expect no print')
if (num2 & 0x3200) == 0x3200:
   print('I should be printed')
```

Expected Result

```
I should be printed
```

Actual Result:

```
I would expect no print
I should be printed
```

P.S: In my script the String is stored in a pandas DataFrame and with this code i check for the header

```
df2 = df.loc[(df['Telegram_Header'].apply(int, args=(2,)) & 0x3200).eq(0x3200)]
```

Comment: The & operation occurs bit by bit. If you want to isolate the last 16 bits of your nums, do `(num1 & 0xFFFF) == 0x3200` resp. `(num2 & 0xFFFF) == 0x3200` instead

Comment: @Tranbi thank you! This works for me! I thought if i compare the 64 bit with `0x3200` it would have the same outcome, since only the "Header-Bits" were set and the rest is 0. To understand it better how would I check a bit sequence in between than? For example Bits 16 to 31?

Comment: I recommend reading about [bitwise operations](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/). To isolate bits 16 to 31, use a corresponding mask and shift to the right: `(num1 & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16` or `(num1 >> 16) & 0xFFFF`